# Unable to pass a byte[] array to a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, arrays

I am creating a webservice client which sends a byte array to the webservice. I think only the address of the byte array is being passed. If that is the situation how can a webservice located in a remote computer identify the address of a bytearray located in my computer.
I am supposed to upload a file after encoding it and saving it as bytearray. The data type mentioned in the wsdl is byte[]. So i doubt if i can use "object" to pass the data.

I simply tried passing the bytearray as it is. It did not work for me. Help please.

Comment: What makes you think the address is being passed? What happened when you tried just passing the byte array? Have you looked at what's being sent on the network?

Comment: I tried to print the value I am sending. It looks like an address and not like the regular base64 encoded data. Not sure if I am doing it right though.

Comment: Where did you try printing the value? At the sending side or the receiving side? All you're seeing is the result of calling `toString()` on a byte array, which is never useful. Use `Arrays.toString(byte[])` instead. I suspect you haven't actually got a problem.

Comment: I don't have access to the receiving side. I tried printing myarray.tostring() , still looks like a reference. Is it possible to pass a reference of an arrray to a webservice in remote system ?

Comment: whats the type specified for this byte array in your wsdl?

Comment: Yes, you're calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` which doesn't give you a particularly useful result. It sounds like you have no evidence that your code is actually failing - if the only thing that's suggesting there's something wrong is that calling `toString()` gives you output such as `[B@89ffb18` then there's really *nothing* to suggest there's anything wrong. What does the web service *do* with the byte array? If it stores it somewhere, can you check that storage afterwards?

Comment: that is my problem. I cannot check the storage. But I am supposed to get a result 1 if my encoded file has been passed successfully, 0 otherwise. I am getting a 0. Anyway one last doubt. What will the receiving side get when I pass an array as an argument ? is it reference or its contents ? If it is the reference alone how will the remote computer identify the memory in my computer ?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia : Its base64Binary

Comment: @antony.ouseph.k, if you send the data with base64, you should be seeing a string with a similar structure to this one: `U2FtcGxlIGJhc2U2NCBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZyE=`. This string has to be decoded to a byte array on the other side. Can you show the significant part of your code and/or request/respone sample of your service?

Comment: I cant sent the encoded data as a string as it wont match with the service method in the wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you are not sending a huge size file.  Then, you should try by referencing your web service from a dummy client app. you can easily develop to test and see where something goes wrong. If you call your method from web service by debugging your method call codes, I guess you will be able to find out what the problem really is.

I hope you will fix it out soon.